# Opening Old MapInfo Workspaces

Tags: mapinfo

I have many "old" (10+ year) MapInfo workspaces that I want to reopen but cannot locate some of the tables. MapInfo will not open the workspaces without these tables and the data/objects I want only exist in the editable layer of these old workspaces. Is there a way of overiding MapInfo's inability to open the workspace without these tables??

Answer (score 4):

Mark,
With MapInfo Professional 11.5.1 we added a feature that we have called "Broken Workspace Opening improvements". This new feature will let you skip tables that can't be opened and just open what can be found.

Maybe that can do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**Workspace Resolver v1.1** will help you delete broken data sources

[image]

This can be found via MapInfo Pro 11.5.1

Tools>Tools Manager and select 'Workspace Resolver' (at the bottom)
This Tool should be located in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MapInfo\Professional\Tools\WorkspaceResolver.MBX' (if installed with defaults on the c: drive)

Answer (score 0):

Mapinfo work spaces are actually just text files: try opening them with an editor (take a backup to be sure) and remove all references to the broken tables. They should look like:

```
Open Table "USA\USA_MAPS\USZIPBDY" As USZIPBDY Interactive
Open Table "USA\USA_MAPS\LANDMRKS" As LANDMRKS Interactive
Open Table "USA\USA_MAPS\US_CNTY" As US_CNTY Interactive
```

Example taken from:
http://www.sgsi.com/MIUserGroup/WorEditing_PhilWoods/Workspace-Presentation.htm

Comment: It's easy to remove the line opening the table, but that will just move the error further down the process of opening the workspace. You can easily find the reference to the table in the Map statement, but in the Set Map statements MapBasic refers to the layer numbers, not the table names. So this might get very complicated if the table is used in a number of maps with many layers.

Answer (score 0):

When a workspace won't open because it's looking for tables I don't have / can't locate then I've got two methods I normally use.

One is the to open the workspace in notepad and delete the line that commands the workspace to open that table (which is pretty much the same method as above).

The other method is to create 'fake tables' for it to open instead. For example, let's say the workspace won't open because it's looking for a table called "Polygons_1" in 'My Documents'. Then copy and paste an old tab file (along with it's corresponding files) into 'My Documents and rename those files as, in this case, "Polygons_1". Then retry opening the workspace.

This method isn't successful 100% of the time and isn't very quick if there's more than one TAB file that the workspace is looking for, but it's done the trick for me quite a few times.

With ArcGIS a workspace opens regardless of whether or not it can find required files and asks you locate them after it's opened, which is much better when you only want do check out the printing layout for example.

Answer (score 0):

The new release MapInfo Professional v.12 allow you to skip tables that are not found and to open the workspace anyway directly. If you dont have access to this release, open the workspace in text editor and change the path of those missing tables.